# Swift - Rate App

Tags: ios, url, app-store

I'm trying to add a Rate App button on my iOS Application and I've looked everywhere online by trying different ways of doing it but none of them have worked.

Here's what I've tried

1.

```
let appId = 1040912970
@IBAction func btnRateApp(sender: UIButton) {
let url = "itunes.apple.com/app/id\(appId)"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: url)!)
}
```

2.

```
let appId = 1040912970
@IBAction func btnRateApp(sender: UIButton) {
let urlString = "http://itunes.apple.com/app/id\(appId)?mt=8"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
```

3.

```
@IBAction func btnRateApp(sender: UIButton) {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: url)!)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wsw-song-chants/id1040912970?ls=1&mt=8")!);
}
```

4.

```
@IBAction func btnRateApp(sender: UIButton) {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1040912970")!);
}
```

When do this one above and click the button, a message on the output console will say

> ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme itms-apps Message
>   from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15

I've also checked if my app Id is correct which shows on itunes connect.

Comment: Have you tried changing `let urlString = "http://itunes.apple.com/app/id\(appId)?mt=8"` to `"http://itunes.apple.com/app/id1040912970?mt=8"`?

Comment: Test it on a real device, not in the simulator.

Comment: Yup. Says page is invalid like the rest except for the last one that gives an output error.

Comment: Just tested it on my iphone. Looks like it works without the simulator. Thanks for helping guys.appriceate it.

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost you must use store-kit in order to actually have in-app ratings.

Secondly check [iRate GitHub Page](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate)

It's a very common requirement and this Library will handle it.